# why is my liquidsoap make install command failing

Tags: compiling, make

I've got a make install command that's failing. I am building liquidsoap  1.2.x to create a .dev file. I'm very very new to building software. I googled for the various, uncommented the stuff in packages, (by the way that goes against the grain of how I  normally do things), did make, then tried make install.

I got the following output:

make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-cry'
make -C src all
make[2]: Entering directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-cry/src'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-cry/src'
ocamlc -a    -I /home/ke7zum/.opam/system/lib/bytes          \
                  -o cry.cma  cry_ssl.cmo cry.cmo
make[3]: Leaving directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-cry/src'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-cry/src'
make[3]:`cry.cmxa' is up to date.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-cry/src'
make[2]: Leaving directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-cry/src'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-cry'
make[1]: Entering directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-mad'
make -C src
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-mad/src'
make[3]: Entering directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-mad/src'
make[3]: `libmad_stubs.a' is up to date.
make[3]:`mad.cma' is up to date.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-mad/src'
make[3]: Entering directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-mad/src'
make[3]: `libmad_stubs.a' is up to date.
make[3]:`mad.cmxa' is up to date.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-mad/src'
make[2]: Leaving directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-mad/src'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-mad'
make[1]: Entering directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-taglib'
make -C src all
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-taglib/src'
make[3]: Entering directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-taglib/src'
make[3]: `libtaglib_stubs.a' is up to date.
make[3]:`taglib.cma' is up to date.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-taglib/src'
make[3]: Entering directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-taglib/src'
make[3]: `libtaglib_stubs.a' is up to date.
make[3]:`taglib.cmxa' is up to date.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-taglib/src'
make[2]: Leaving directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-taglib/src'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-taglib'
make[1]: Entering directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-lame'
make -C src all
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-lame/src'
make[3]: Entering directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-lame/src'
make[3]: `liblame_stubs.a' is up to date.
make[3]:`lame.cma' is up to date.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-lame/src'
make[3]: Entering directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-lame/src'
make[3]: `liblame_stubs.a' is up to date.
make[3]:`lame.cmxa' is up to date.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-lame/src'
rm -f lame_dynlink.cmi
make[2]: Leaving directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-lame/src'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-lame'
make[1]: Entering directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-ogg'
make -C src all
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-ogg/src'
make[3]: Entering directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-ogg/src'
make[3]: `libogg_stubs.a' is up to date.
make[3]:`ogg.cma' is up to date.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-ogg/src'
make[3]: Entering directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-ogg/src'
make[3]: `libogg_stubs.a' is up to date.
make[3]:`ogg.cmxa' is up to date.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-ogg/src'
make[2]: Leaving directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-ogg/src'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-ogg'
make[1]: Entering directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-vorbis'
make -C src all
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-vorbis/src'
make[3]: Entering directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-vorbis/src'
make[3]: `libvorbis_stubs.a' is up to date.
make[3]:`vorbis.cma' is up to date.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-vorbis/src'
make[3]: Entering directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-vorbis/src'
make[3]: `libvorbis_stubs.a' is up to date.
make[3]:`vorbis.cmxa' is up to date.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-vorbis/src'
make[2]: Leaving directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-vorbis/src'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-vorbis'
make[1]: Entering directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-speex'
make -C src all
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-speex/src'
make[3]: Entering directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-speex/src'
make[3]: `libspeex_stubs.a' is up to date.
make[3]:`speex.cma' is up to date.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-speex/src'
make[3]: Entering directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-speex/src'
make[3]: `libspeex_stubs.a' is up to date.
make[3]:`speex.cmxa' is up to date.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-speex/src'
make[2]: Leaving directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-speex/src'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-speex'
make[1]: Entering directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-opus'
make -C src
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-opus/src'
make[3]: Entering directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-opus/src'
make[3]: `libopus_stubs.a' is up to date.
make[3]:`opus.cma' is up to date.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-opus/src'
make[3]: Entering directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-opus/src'
make[3]: `libopus_stubs.a' is up to date.
make[3]:`opus.cmxa' is up to date.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-opus/src'
make[2]: Leaving directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-opus/src'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-opus'
make[1]: Entering directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-schroedinger'
make -C src all
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-schroedinger/src'
make[3]: Entering directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-schroedinger/src'
make[3]: `libschroedinger_stubs.a' is up to date.
make[3]:`schroedinger.cma' is up to date.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-schroedinger/src'
make[3]: Entering directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-schroedinger/src'
make[3]: `libschroedinger_stubs.a' is up to date.
make[3]:`schroedinger.cmxa' is up to date.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-schroedinger/src'
make[2]: Leaving directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-schroedinger/src'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-schroedinger'
make[1]: Entering directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-voaacenc'
make -C src all
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-voaacenc/src'
make[3]: Entering directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-voaacenc/src'
make[3]: `libvoaacenc_stubs.a' is up to date.
make[3]:`voaacenc.cma' is up to date.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-voaacenc/src'
make[3]: Entering directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-voaacenc/src'
make[3]: `libvoaacenc_stubs.a' is up to date.
make[3]:`voaacenc.cmxa' is up to date.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-voaacenc/src'
make[2]: Leaving directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-voaacenc/src'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-voaacenc'
make[1]: Entering directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-flac'
make -C src all
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-flac/src'
make[3]: Entering directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-flac/src'
make[3]: `libflac_stubs.a' is up to date.
make[3]:`flac.cma' is up to date.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-flac/src'
make[3]: Entering directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-flac/src'
make[3]: `libflac_stubs.a' is up to date.
make[3]:`flac.cmxa' is up to date.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-flac/src'
make[2]: Leaving directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-flac/src'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-flac'
make[1]: Entering directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-dtools'
make -C src
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-dtools/src'
make[3]: Entering directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-dtools/src'
make[3]: `dtools.cma' is up to date.
make[3]: Leaving directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-dtools/src'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-dtools/src'
make[3]:`dtools.cmxa' is up to date.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-dtools/src'
make[2]: Leaving directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-dtools/src'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-dtools'
make[1]: Entering directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-duppy'
make -C src all
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-duppy/src'
make[3]: Entering directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-duppy/src'
make[3]: `libduppy_stubs.a' is up to date.
make[3]:`duppy.cma' is up to date.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-duppy/src'
make[3]: Entering directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-duppy/src'
make[3]: `libduppy_stubs.a' is up to date.
make[3]:`duppy.cmxa' is up to date.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-duppy/src'
make[2]: Leaving directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-duppy/src'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-duppy'
make[1]: Entering directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-mm'
make -C src all
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-mm/src'
make[3]: Entering directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-mm/src'
make[3]: `libmm_stubs.a' is up to date.
ocamlc -a -dllib dllmm_stubs.so    -I .. -I /home/ke7zum/.opam/system/lib/alsa -I /home/ke7zum/.opam/system/lib/pulseaudio -I /home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-mm/../ocaml-mad/src -I /home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-mm/../ocaml-ogg/src -I /home/ke7zum/.opam/system/lib/bytes -linkall        -cclib -lmm_stubs    -o mm.cma ringbuffer.cmo IO.cmo audio.cmo image.cmo video.cmo MIDI.cmo synth.cmo
make[3]: Leaving directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-mm/src'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-mm/src'
make[3]:`libmm_stubs.a' is up to date.
make[3]: `mm.cmxa' is up to date.
make[3]: Leaving directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-mm/src'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-mm/src'
make[1]: Leaving directory`/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/ocaml-mm'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/liquidsoap'
Makefile.rules:10: Makefile.defs: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** No rule to make target`Makefile.defs'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ke7zum/liquidsoap-full/liquidsoap'
make: *** [all] Error 1
]0;ke7zum@test: ~/liquidsoap-fullke7zum@test:~/liquidsoap-full$ exit
exitI have no clue where it is failing as I was trying not to install "jack" and other things my virtual box might not need. What do I need to check to see  this is not going to fail again. I followed the faster method by using the liquidsoap full tar file Instructions located [here.](http://liquidsoap.fm/doc-svn/build.html):

```
# Configure all libraries and packages.

# You may pass extra options such as --enable-debugging,
# --prefix, --sysconfdir, --localstatedir, etc.
./configure

# Now, build all libraries and liquidsoap
make

# To install liquidsoap,
# you usually need to type the following as root
make install
```

To help things outa  bit  [here is the output of my configure](http://upload.tffppodcast.com/typescript1). I'm  trying not to  put a lot of output here.  I actually don't remember seeing these errors the last time  I did this, which was this morning.

Comment: OK, I have added the outputs into the question itself.  Now, (1) this is probably the most common form of software distribution using autoconf (2) it does not really use automake which would have been even more common, instead it requires GNU make (which will work well on linux but not that well on other *nix, at least with the default install).  (3) [`./configure`](https://github.com/savonet/liquidsoap/blob/master/configure.ac) prints a end of config message, it is very useful to know what that did tell you (add it to the question).

Comment: Ok, I added the output of my ./config command. I   hope that is still linked appropriately. I have no clue what's up, it looks like it will work, then config throws up, to put it nicely. I'm trying to cancel the ones that won't build especially as I won't be using those parts of liquidsoap.